# Upload CSV payload to Google Storage using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload string payload to Google Storage directly using Ruby. But, it seems there's no direct way to do this without creating a temporary file in the disk.

I am using the CSV library to generate a string payload.

Current method suggests to store the string payload in a temporary file and then use code something like below to upload the file to google storage:

```rb
  require "google/cloud/storage"

  storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new
  bucket  = storage.bucket bucket_name

  file = bucket.create_file local_file_path, file_name
```

Is there a way to avoid creating a temporary file to upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the documentation where it states that we can use `any File-like object such as StringIO` to upload string payload directly.

Here's my code:

```
require "google/cloud/storage"

storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new

bucket = storage.bucket "my-todo-app"
bucket.create_file StringIO.new("Hello world!"), "hello-world.txt"
```

Go to `Creating a File` section of this [link](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/index.html) for example

Documentation Link:
https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/Google/Cloud/Storage/Bucket.html#create_file-instance_method